# a function as an infinite series of e

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory

My literature is rather lacking, and I can't seem to find one that tackles this kind of infinite series:

$$ f(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{g(n)x} $$

The goal is to find $g(n)$ given $f(x)$. What area of mathematics would I need to study to approach this kind of problem?

Answer (score 1):

First off, $f(x)$ had better be positive (or avoid the negative reals if complex), since each term of the series is an exponential.  Second, if we substitute $y=e^x$, then your RHS becomes the series $$\sum_{n\ge 1} y^{g(n)}$$
Hence the RHS is a special kind of power series, where each coefficient is $0$ or $1$ (if $g(n)$ is injective), or a nonnegative integer (if $g(n)$ is not necessarily injective).  This restriction means that only certain $f(x)$ are allowed, in addition to the positive restriction.  I don't know of a lot of results in this area, but you can read a little bit [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerSeries.html).